# Sharepoint 2013 newform.aspx trying to disable save button until multiple check boxes are ticked

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I use the below to disable until first textbox is rticked but how to add further checkboxes as i have 4 in total

```html
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"                             type="text/javascript"></script>
 
        <script language="javascript">
 
        $(document).ready(function(){
        //Disable the "Save" button initially
        $("input[value$='Save']").attr('disabled', true);  
 
        //alert('jQuery Works');
 
        //Enable-Disable "Save" button based on "I Agree" checkbox value!
        $("input[title$='checkbox field name here']").click(function(){
        if(this.checked)
           {
            $("input[value$='Save']").attr('disabled', false);
           }      
        else
           {
            $("input[value$='Save']").attr('disabled', true);  
           }
         }); 
 
          });
 
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could use the preSaveAction function to execute the code written for validation on click of Save button.

Below is my demo code for you:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"                             type="text/javascript"></script>
 
<script language="javascript">
 function PreSaveAction() {
    var Checkbox = $("input[title='Checkbox']");
    var Checkbox2 = $("input[title='Checkbox2']");
    if($(Checkbox).is(":checked")  && $(Checkbox2).is(":checked")){
    
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert('Please make sure all check boxes are ticked');
        return false
    }
}   
            
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this i have added it to a script editor web part but it doent seem to call it when i click the save button, nothing happens the form is not saved.  If i tick all the checkboxes or dont tick any of them it still does nothing no warning message i have wrapped the code in <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I have updated my code, check if that works for you.